# basic PHP API configuration - need to shorten php api code

Tags: php, api

I'm trying to figure out a way to shorten the php code that will display every asteroid name in the NASA's neo (near earth objects) API : https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/browse?page=0

So far I'm using something like this:

```
echo "<h4>//The asteroid name:</h4>";
echo( $data["near_earth_objects"]["2010-05-29"][2]["name"]);
```

Is there a more efficient way I can configure the php code to automatically grab every "$data["near_earth_objects"]" from the api code with the nasa's link to the asteroid info?

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: Your link is missing an API key, is this the data you are getting? https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2015-09-07&end_date=2015-09-08&api_key=DEMO_KEY

Comment: Unclear what you're hoping to achieve. You're clearly already accessing the JSON and successfully decoding it into a PHP array.  If you're bothered by the length of the `$data["near_earth_objects"]...`, simply assign `$neo = $data["near_earth_objects"]` and use `$neo["2010-05-29"][2]["name"]`, etc.

Comment: I think you're asking about how to iterate over the result set right? As in how to use a loop?